Drogon framework MAKE throws error for postgresql
I am using cpm.cmake to install the dependencies for drogon on MAC (Intel)
Postgresql was installed using
brew install postgresql

Also installed the libpq
brew install liqpq



include(cmake/CPM.cmake)
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME drogon
        VERSION 1.9.7
        GITHUB_REPOSITORY drogonframework/drogon
        GIT_TAG v1.9.7
)

This downloads the drogon, but on running make it throws many exceptions for pgBatchConnection
/build/_deps/drogon-src/orm_lib/src/postgresql_impl/PgBatchConnection.cc:84:7: error: member initializer 'autoBatch_' does not name a non-static data member or base class

build/_deps/drogon-src/orm_lib/src/postgresql_impl/PgBatchConnection.cc:126:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sendBatchedSql'



What happens if you download and build drogon without CPM? Any compile errors you get will also depend on the version of libpq you installed

I built drogon from source (using cmake) and that worked

Same version? If so, you will have to figure out what CPM does differently

yeah, it's same version. Will look into it. Thanks :)
